# Exiting a Javascript Program when a certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, exit

I've been looking everywhere and can't find a way to exit a javascript program when a condition is met. Is there something like `exit` that I can't find?
Here is an example:

```
if (number > 5) {
console.log(number);
//Then exits the entire program and does not execute any of the code following the closing bracket of this 'if' statement
}
//other commands and lines of code
```

Comment: Is this for a browser or node?

Comment: Assuming this is a Node.js application, you can use `process.exit()`

Answer (score 0):

Two fairly simply options for JavaScript running on a browser are to:

- Throw an exception to stop the rest of the script getting called
- Add your code inside a function and use `return` values

### Exception example

```
if (number > 5) {
  console.log(number);
  throw Error("EXIT CODE");
}
```

### Return example

```
function test() {
  if (number > 5) {
    console.log(number);
    return;
  }
}
```